# How are claims created and inherited?

Tags: crusader-kings-2

Each claim to a title has two properties:

1. whether it's weak or strong
2. whether it's inheritable or not

Each of the 4 possible combinations of the two properties is possible.

Since I didn't find any detailed explanation, I was wondering: How exactly are claims inherited? When does a strong claim become weak upon inheritance? Can an inheritable claim become not inheritable upon inheritance? If yes, when exactly does that happen?

Also, what are the ways “new” claims can be created? I know you can create a claim using Chancellor, and I think you also receive a claim on title if you lose that title in war. Are there other options?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The strong claim does not become weak, but the strong claim can only distribute to first 3 children, the remaining would get a weak claim. You can have more information from [here](http://ckiiwiki.com/Claims).

1. You can get claim via marriage. Marry someone who has an inheritable claim. Your children will have the claim.
2. You can also get de jure ducal claim by creating/unsurping duchy title although the claim does not appear in the claim list. The same goes for Kingdom and Empire.
3. Invite pretenders into your court, and then grant him landed title.

Visit the [wiki](http://crusaderkings-two.wikia.com/wiki/Casus_Belli_%28usage_and_claims%29) for more information.

Comment: So, what about non-inheritable claims, where do they come from?

Comment: The claim is inheritable, but their sons/daughters will have the claim as non inheritable. And after them, the claim goes away.